# Bind json data to Kendo UI

Tags: jquery, json, kendo-ui, telerik, json.net

I created my first Kendo chart. Chart is success with manual data. But when i bind with json chart is not binding correctly.

when i check the data url it gives as the following

[{\"Name\":\"Name1\",\"Age\":20},{\"Name\":\"Name2\",\"Age\":23},{\"Name\":\"Name3\",\"Age\":28}]

The data is serialized using json.net. I can use this string in serverside using JsonTextReader. Also it is working in Console.WriteLine.

When i try with ajax in jquery the alert also gives the correct data without any escape character.

But the data not binding to the kendo chart. I read one forum from telerik that the json string must be valid. the forum link is

http://www.telerik.com/forums/json-databing-for-the-chart

Exactly the json string i got in browser like specified in the forum. So where the problem is. If the data not valid how i serialize in wcf to return the valid json using json.net

My chart bind method like exactly in the demo using transport.

Comment: Can you please provide the codes, so we can look into it. Thanks

Comment: sure i will give. Actually the problem araise when i directly bind data from service url

Comment: I bind using tranport section in the chart bind exactly like in the kendo ui demo. But now i changed to ajax web service call and response is parsed and bind to chart as datasource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out. Using ajax call i set the data  in global variable by setting async = false. When assign i just parse the data to json and bind from the data variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending something like the following:

```
"{\"data\":
  [
    {\"Name\":\"Name1\",\"Age\":20},
    {\"Name\":\"Name2\",\"Age\":23},
    {\"Name\":\"Name3\",\"Age\":28}
  ]
}"
```

Comment: can you please provide the codes so i can try locally??